# hide and show in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, code-behind

I have an object that i want to hide. it is a row from a datagrid on my website. The data from the grid is dynamic. I want this row to hide/not be visible when i click on my selection of "computer" in my dropdownlist. i think i have to use getElementById().

This is the id that i want to hide

```
<span id="dg_form_ctl05_lbl_show_tag" style="display:inline-block;background-color:Transparent;border-color:Navy;border-width:3px;border-style:Double;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;width:130px;">Subject*</span>
```

this is the dropdownlist id. `dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1`

This is the code that i have so far but it doesn't seem correct because it's not hiding the row when i run it.

```
function hideMe() {
var g = document.getElementById("dg_form_ctl05_lbl_show_tag");
var e = document.getElementById("dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1");
if(e == "Computer") 
g.style.display = 'none';
}
```

I think i need to use code-behind on this also here is the code i have so far for c#.

```
  if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("hwa"))
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hwa", "hideMe();", true);
        }
```

can someone help me?

Comment: `if(e == "Computer")` is where you are going wrong. The object that is found by the getElementById function _will never be equal to a string_

Comment: oh right okay i added a .value to the e = document.getElementById("dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1");

Comment: Food for thought: It took you longer to write the question than it would have to do even the most basic of debug tests. A simple alert in the conditional would have shown it never evaluates to true, which leads you to examine the values in the conditional which should've resulted in the obvious "duh" moment of realizing you are comparing a DOM element to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `value` property for getting the value of the select element, currently you are comparing a `string` with an `object`, try this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1").value;
```

Comment: Okay I had that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideMe() {
    var g = document.getElementById("dg_form_ctl05_lbl_show_tag");
    var e = document.getElementById("dg_form_ctl02_DropDownList1").value;
    if(e == "Computer") 
    g.style.display = 'none';
}
```